# Why does a search-thingy appear on startup all of a sudden?

Tags: unity, gnome

[image]

Why does this appear right after login in all of a sudden? It's in the middle of my primary monitor. When I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> it disappears.

It started to show up the other day for no apparent reason. It has kept showing up after every login since then.

What does it do and how do I get ridd of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like [Gnome-Do](http://do.davebsd.com/) (or [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) with a [Gnome-Do theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/synapse-launcher-update-brings-new-theme-options/)).

If it's Gnome-Do, you can prevent it from opening on startup by pressing the down arrow in the top-right corner and going to preferences.  Under the "General" tab, you can choose "Hide window on first launch" to prevent this box from opening on startup.

[image: GNOME Do Preferences window]

Or, if you don't use Gnome Do, you can safely uninstall it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I have no idea why gnome-do was installed and did this so out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

That would look to be Gnome-Do.  If not needed, ensure that it is not set to start upon startup.